# Xcode build parameters

Tags: objective-c, xcode, build

I am looking at compiling building a simple app I have wrote using Objective C. Currently all the application does it print 'hello [dev|production]' on screen.

What I would like to do is able to add a build parameter into xcode so that if I build it with a dev flag then the output would be 'hello dev' else the output would be 'hello production'.

Can someone give me an code example or link to a resource which will allow me to do this.

The idea is not to distingusish between DEBUG and PRODUCTION but rather to be able to add values into the build process which will change the compiled application output.

Comment: You can steel use #ifdef DEBUG or not?

Comment: @duDE I had noticed this but I was after a way of begining able to produce different builds by changing a flag, for example being able to add a build parameter called `home` which could then also produce a build which would say `hello home` ---> NOTE, i know about command line arguments and i am not looking for this.

Comment: So you want to write an APPLICATION that accepts command line parameters or you want to do an XCode build from the command line and pass a #define option to XCode itself?

Answer (score 3):

You can add another value to your preprocessor Macros, here:

[image]

If you want to add a another build configuration:
[image]

**Edit 1:**

> The idea is not to distingusish between DEBUG and PRODUCTION but
>   rather to be able to add values into the build process which will
>   change the compiled application output.

Something you can do is to have two plist files, with all the values you want to use in your application. If you are in debug mode use debug.plist file, otherwise release.plist. This allows you to better control what are you using in your application for each build.

You can find the configurations here:

[image]

(I used PlotCreator as an example... It's an open source lib)

Comment: If the goal is to distinguish between Debug / Release, it's enough to use the `#ifdef DEBUG` and then take about the String with you want to show...

Comment: Where would I find the Configurations?

Comment: @JackyBoy Re Edit1, how would I do this? I this is my first time using xcode so its quite a learning curve.

Comment: The plists or the configurations?

Comment: I'd be careful putting configuration information into plists as these are easily extractable from apps and you may not always want a techy end user to start poking around especially if it's information related to connecting to external services